# How to configure store with a root reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying setting up a store to contain state for two different pieces of my application: a todo app and a counter. But I'm persistently getting `TypeError: store.getState is not a function` in the browser

So I have set up two reducers, one for the counter `counterReducer` and another for the messages`messageReducer`.

here is code for my message reducer

```
const ADD = "ADD";

export const messageReducer = (messageState = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD:
      return messageState.concat(action.message);
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      break;
    default:
      return messageState;
  }
};
```

here is code for my counter reducer

```
const DECREMENT = "DECREMENT";

export const counterReducer = (counterState = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INCREMENT:
      return counterState + 1;
    case DECREMENT:
      return counterState - 1;
    default:
      return counterState;
  }
};
```

I'm using combineReducers to get the root reducer as shown below

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { messageReducer } from "./messageReducer";
import { counterReducer } from "./counterReducer";

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  message: messageReducer,
  counter: counterReducer
});
```

Here is my store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { rootReducer } from "./reducers/rootReducer";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

export const store = (state = {}) => {
  return createStore(rootReducer, state, applyMiddleware(thunk));
};
```

Here is my provider file where i provide the store to my app

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { store } from "./store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
```

finally, here is my app with the presentational components and the connect functionality

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import "./App.css";
import { addMessage } from "./actions/addMessage";
import { increment } from "./actions/increment";
import { decrement } from "./actions/decrement";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    messages: state.messageState,
    count: state.counterState
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  increaseCounter: () => dispatch(increment()),
  decreaseCounter: () => dispatch(decrement()),
  submitNewMessage: message => dispatch(addMessage(message))
});

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.submitMessage = this.submitMessage.bind(this);
    this.onIncrement = this.onIncrement.bind(this);
    this.onDecrement = this.onDecrement.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
  }

  submitMessage() {
    this.setState({
      input: ""
    });
    this.props.submitNewMessage(this.state.input);
  }

  onIncrement() {
    this.props.increaseCounter();
  }

  onDecrement() {
    this.props.decreaseCounter();
  }

  render() {
    const messagesRender = this.props.messages.map(item => <li>{item}</li>);
    const styles = {
      container: {
        display: "grid",
        justifyItems: "center"
      }
    };
    return (
      <div style={styles.container}>
        <div>
          <h2>Type in a new Message:</h2>
          {/* render an input, button, and ul here */}
          <input value={this.state.input} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <button onClick={this.submitMessage}>submit</button>
          <ul>{messagesRender}</ul>
          {/* change code above this line */}
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>Counter App</h2>
          <button onClick={this.onIncrement}>Increment</button>
          <button onClick={this.onDecrement}>Decrement</button>
          <div>{this.props.count}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

Here is the error I'm getting. Somebody please reachout
[image]

Comment: I don't have a provider.js file@Federkun

Comment: do you need to call ` <Provider store={store()}>`?

Comment: I believe what @Federkun says is correct. What you are exporting from store is actually a function that creates the store, not the actual store itself.

Comment: Thanks, that actually did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In your store file you are exporting a function that creates a store rather than a store object itself.

If you don't need to set the initial state, you can change your `store.js` to be:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export store;
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. I actually realized I could do it this way